# Trouble understanding steps in convolution

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

This problem comes from Brian Fisher and Biljana Jolevska-Tuneska's 2010 paper ['On the logarithmic integral'](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228382485_On_the_logarithmic_integral). As it is freely available I will refer to it rather than copy large chunks here that will undoubtably make things more unclear.

Given $(f * g)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)g(x-t)dt$

they show that, 
[image]

using where PV is the Cauchy principle value,

[image]

Now whilst step 1 is not clear how it relates to $(f * g)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)g(x-t)dt$, though it might be something to do with $(f * g)(x)=[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx][\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)dt]$ as shown [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html), I do not understand then how they get from 1 to 2 then to 3? Step 4 is fairly obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the definitions of $\operatorname{li}_+$ and $x_+$:
$$
\operatorname{li}_+(x) = \begin{cases}
\mathrm{PV} \int_0^x \frac{dt}{\ln t}, & x>0 \\
0 & x \leq 0
\end{cases}
$$

$$
x_+ = \begin{cases}
x & x>0 \\
0 & x\leq 0
\end{cases}
$$

I will skip the prefix $\mathrm{PV}$ though.

Now, by definition of convolution,
$$
(\operatorname{li}_+ * x_+^r)(x)
= (x_+^r * \operatorname{li}_+)(x)
= \int_0^\infty (x-t)_+^r \operatorname{li}_+(t) \, dt
$$
Here, $(x-t)_+$ vanishes if $x-t<0,$ i.e. if $t>x$. Therefore,
$$
\int_0^\infty (x-t)_+^r \operatorname{li}_+(t) \, dt
= \int_0^x (x-t)^r \operatorname{li}_+(t) \, dt
$$

Then we insert the definition of $\operatorname{li}_+$ and get
$$
\int_0^x (x-t)^r \left( \int_0^t \frac{du}{\ln u} \right) \, dt
$$

The next step is to make a change of order of integration. The domain of integration is $\{ (t,u) \mid 0 < t < x, \ 0 < u < t \}$ which can also be written $\{ (t,u) \mid 0 < u < x, \ u < t < x \},$ so
$$
\int_0^x (x-t)^r \left( \int_0^t \frac{du}{\ln u} \right) \, dt
= \int_0^x \frac{1}{\ln u} \left( \int_u^x (x-t)^r \, dt \right) \, du
$$

Then we evaluate the inner integral,
$$
\int_u^x (x-t)^r \, dt
= \left[ \frac{(-1)^r (x-t)^{r+1}}{r+1} \right]_{t=u}^x 
= \frac{(u-x)^{r+1}}{r+1}
$$

By the binomial theorem, $(u-x)^{r+1} = \sum_{i=0}^{r+1} { r+1 \choose i } (-1)^i x^i u^{r+1-i}$. Inserting this we get step 3.

Comment: thank you for the answer, actually I cannot get step 4 as I thought I could easily do $\int_0^x \frac{u^{r-i+1}}{\ln u} du$. Perhaps you could complete that step in the answer?

Comment: @onepound. By Lemma 2.1 in the paper,
$$\mathrm{PV} \int_0^x \frac{t^{r-1}}{\ln |t|} dt = \operatorname{li}(x^r) = \operatorname{li}_+(x^r)$$
when $x>0$. Replace $r$ with $r-i+2$ in it to get what's changing from step 3 to step 4.

Comment: yes I see it now thanks again.